# Why isn't java typesafe when inferring array types?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, type-inference, type-safety

I was playing around with generics and found that, to my surprise, the following code compiles:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

class Generic<T> {
    private T instance;
    public Generic(T instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public T get(){ return instance; }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fArray(new B[1], new Generic<A>(new A())); // <-- No error here
    }

    public static <T> void fArray(T[] a, Generic<? extends T> b) {
        a[0] = b.get();
    }
}
```

I would expect `T` to be inferred to `B`. `A` does not extend `B`. So why doesn't the compiler complain about it?

`T` seems to be inferred to `Object`, since I can pass a `Generic<Object>` as well.

Moreover, **when actually running the code**, it throws an `ArrayStoreException` on the `a[0] = b.get();` line.

I'm not using any raw generic types. I feel like this exception could have been avoided with a compile time error, or at least a warning, if `T` was actually inferred to be `B`.

---

When further testing with the `List<...>` equivalent:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    fList(new ArrayList<B>(), new Generic<A>(new A())); // <-- Error, as expected
}

public static <T> void fList(List<T> a, Generic<? extends T> b) {
    a.add(b.get());
}
```

This does produce and error:

```
The method fList(List<T>, Generic<? extends T>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<B>, Generic<A>)
```

As does the more generic case:

```
public static <T> void fList(List<? extends T> a, Generic<? extends T> b) {
    a.add(b.get()); // <-- Error here
}
```

The compiler correctly recognizes that the first `?` might be further down the inheritance hierarchy than the second `?`.

e.g. If the first `?` were `B` and the second `?` were `A` then this isn't type safe.

---

So why doesn't the first example produce a similar compiler error? Is it just an oversight? Or is there a technical limitation?

The only way I could produce an error is by explicitly providing a type:

```
Main.<B>fArray(new B[1], new Generic<A>(new A())); // <-- Not applicable
```

---

I didn't really find anything through my own research, except for [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety) from 2005 (before generics), which talks about the dangers of array covariance.

Array covariance seems to hint towards an explanation, but I can't think of one.

---

Current jdk is 1.8.0.0_91

Comment: I wonder if you might be bumping up against Java's type erasure in generics? Just a thought, I don't have time to look at the closer ATM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

class Generic<T> {
    private T instance;
    public Generic(T instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public T get(){ return instance; }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fArray(new B[1], new Generic<A>(new A())); // <-- No error here
    }

    public static <T> void fArray(T[] a, Generic<? extends T> b) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(a[0]);
        list.add(b.get());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the signatures used to infer the type parameters are identical, the only thing that's different is that `fArray()` only reads array elements instead of writing them, making the `T -> A` inference perfectly justifiable at runtime.

And there is no way for the compiler to tell what your array reference will be used for in the implementation of the method.

Comment: @JornVernee Yeah, I overdid it but you get the general idea. There is no reason for the compiler to choose `T -> B` when `T -> A` satisfies all criteria.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty nice. But the point is that you want to add extra type safety by saying that ```?``` must always extend ```T``` (i.e. the array type). Just like you do ```A a = new A(); A a1 = a;``` instead of having ```Object a = new A(); A a2 = (A) a;``` Sometimes the 2nd goes just fine (when casting), but to be sure we use the 1st way, because it has type safety.

Comment: @JornVernee Fair enough. How about now? :)

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect T to be inferred to B. A does not extend B. So why doesn't the compiler complain about it?

`T` is not inferred to be `B`, it is inferred to be `A`. Since `B` extends `A`, `B[]` is a subtype of `A[]`, and therefore the method call is correct.

Contrary to generics, the element type of an array is available at runtime (they are *reified*). So when you try to do

```
a[0] = b.get();
```

the runtime environment knows that `a` is actually a `B` array and cannot hold an `A`.

The problem here is that Java is extending dynamically. Arrays are there since the first version of Java, while generics were added only in Java 1.5. In general, Oracle tries to make new Java versions backward compatible, and therefore errors made in earlier versions (the array covariance, for example) are not corrected in newer versions.

Comment: Like I said: _"```T``` seems to be inferred to ```Object```, since I can pass a ```Generic<Object>``` as well."_ But can you tell me _why_ ```T``` is inferred to be ```Object```? Or can you show me a failure case if ```T``` were hypothetically inferred to be ```B``` instead?

Comment: `T` is not inferred as `Object`, because then you would not be able to pass a `Generic<A>` to your method, because `Generic<A>` is not a sub-type of `Generic<Object>`. Of course, if you actually pass a `Generic<Object>` instead of a `Generic<A>`, then `T` is inferred to be an `Object`.

Comment: If ```T``` is ```Object``` then ```Generic<A>``` satisfies ```Generic<? extends T>```. It is further proven by the call ```Main.<Object>fArray(new B[1], new Generic<A>(new A()));```, which compiles without errors.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed the `? extends`. Sorry. The point is, that `T` cannot be inferred to be `B`, because `A` is not a sub-class of `B`. So I don't understand your expactation that `T` should be inferred to be `B`.

Comment: Since I am passing a ```B[]``` and the signature has ```T[]``` as an argument, I would expect ```T``` to be inferred as ```B```. And ```A``` does not extend ```B```. So the whole point is that the first snippet **shouldn't** compile, and the question is asking why it **does** compile.

Comment: But you are not only passing a `B[]`, you are also passing a `Generic<A>`. This bowls down to two constraints: `T[]` must be a supertype`B[]` and `Generic<? extends T>` must be a supertype of `Generic<A>`. These constraints do have a solution, namely `T` is `A` (or `Object`).

Comment: Sure there is a solution. But like I demonstrated, it brakes type safety, and therefore should not be allowed.

Comment: Yes, it breaks type safety. Like I said in my answer, this is because newer Java versions try not to break old code. Back in Java 1.0 times it seemed like a good idea to make arrays covariant, because then you could write 'generic' methods as `void f(Object[] arr)` and still call them with any array type. Now we know better, but we have to live with it.

Comment: I'm willing to except the answer of "it is done for backwards compatibility" if you can actually show me a failure case.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee `Since I am passing a B[] and the signature has T[] as an argument, I would expect T to be inferred as B.`. This is the assumption that fails. Since `new B[1] instanceof A[]`, it's just as valid to infer `T` to be `A` or `Object`. On its own, it would be inferred to be the most specific of those (`B`), but together with the other constraint `A` is chosen instead as it satisfies both constraints.

Comment: I can't, obviously, because legacy code that old doesn't have generics. The point is that the type inference is correct because arrays are covariant in their element type (`B[]` is a sub-type of `A[]`, and therefore `T` can be inferred to be `A`). And making arrays invariant will, although certainly improving Java as a language, break all legacy code where someone tries to call, for example, a method `void f(Object[] arr);` with `f(new A[] { new A() });`.

Comment: @Hoopje Yeah, `Arrays.sort()` would be pretty useless for example.